# Discount Coupon Codes with the opt-in functionality in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, content-builder, marketingcloudapi

I am trying to send the discount coupon codes upon opting-in to my contacts with the below conditions:

1. Initial Opt-in email - Opt-in to our emails and we’ll give you a discount code (click button to opt-in)
2. Coupon code email - Here’s your unique coupon code! You have until this date to use your code. No further action is needed.
3. Reminder Email - Last call for your coupon code! Click this button to opt-in and get a discount code

I want to send the Initial Opt-in email using the journey builder (If the email is opened in a specific number of days) then we will send the reminder email.

I have tried using the [https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_offer_coupon_codes_via_ampscript.htm&type=5]
But not sure how to proceed ahead with the specific requirement

It would be a great help if someone can guide how to achieve the requirement as i am a newbie in the marketing cloud.
Thans in advance

Comment: This is a very broad question, which goes across Ampscript, Journey Builder, Automation Studio, etc. hence it will probably get closed soon. I will advise you to provide more details on what you have tried, and limit the question to e.g. the coupon code Ampscript itself, leaving the journey for later. Also, I don't understand why you send out emails to contacts who have not opted in yet..?